# Find what files were opened to generate PHP page

Tags: php, joomla

I am working with an annoyingly complicated Joomla! site and having to do some customisation to the layout at the code level.

My problem is finding what files to edit.

So, given a certain page, can I log a list of files that get opened during the parsing of it?

Comment: See what template is active, find it and depends on what you are supposed to change edit files for appropriate page. Joomla seems a bit complicated at the beginning but I don't think nothing can save you from heavy digging trough code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tada, here it is: https://www.php.net/get+included+files `get_included_files()`

The comment in the documentation regarding only getting the directly included files is wrong. You always get ALL files included up to the point of execution, regardless of where you make the call to the function.

```
fileB.php
<?php
include 'fileB.php';

fileB.php
<?php
include 'fileC.php

fileC.php
<?php
var_dump(get_included_files());
```

Output:

```
array(3) {
  [0] =>
  string(18) "/path/to/fileA.php"
  [1] =>
  string(18) "/path/to/fileB.php"
  [2] =>
  string(18) "/path/to/fileC.php"
}
```

So if you want to know all files, dumping them is best placed at the end of the file that is called first, e.g. your usual `index.php`.

Comment: That will work, but only from the root level. For example, if page1 includes/requires page2, and page2 requires page3, calling that function on page1 will only return page2 (it wont see that page2 includes/requires page3)

Comment: Geez, I don't wanna use that too much; over 270 files in that list.

Comment: @sven Yip, you are right, maybe it's from an older version of PHP. Just tested it and it works as required